# Finding stray <h2> tag to get W3C validated

Tags: css, validation

I have one error when validating my Joomla built site against the W3C validator. It's a closed  tag but without an opening tag. Problem I'm having is the tag appears to be completely unrelated to any other elements and I can't see it via Firebug. Anyone know how I can track down what's causing this? It's a right pain. Details from the validator:

---

Line 403, Column 5: end tag for element "h2" which is not open

The Validator found an end tag for the above element, but that element is not currently open. This is often caused by a leftover end tag from an element that was removed during editing, or by an implicitly closed element (if you have an error related to an element being used where it is not allowed, this is almost certainly the case). In the latter case this error will disappear as soon as you fix the original problem.

If this error occurred in a script section of your document, you should probably read this FAQ entry.

---

and a snippet of how it appears in the HTML from view source:

---

```
<div id="ja-current-content" class="column" style="width:100%">
<div class="ja-content-main clearfix">
</h2>
<div class="article-content">
<h1>Welcome to SWAYsearch web design, Cambridge</h1>
```

---

The site is: http://www.swaysearch.com

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers

John

Answer (score 1):

That's a known bug when you have title's disabled. You'll have to open that file manually and comment out that if statement which leaves the stray closing h2 tag.

I believe the opening h2 tag is this:

```
<h2 class="contentheading clearfix">
```

Search through your code for that string and you should find your issue.